# Invalid column not detected when #temp table is used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Example:

```
create table dbo.t1 (id int)
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.s_Test') is not null drop proc dbo.s_Test 
GO
create proc dbo.s_Test 
as
    create table #t2 (id2 int)
    select t.id, t.xyz from dbo.t1 t join #t2 t2 on t2.id2 = t.id
GO
```

When the proc s_Test is created, I was expecting an error like "Invalid column name 'xyz', But there is no error at proc creation time. It seems the #temp table seems to have something to do with it, as if I create this version with a table variable:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.s_Test2') is not null drop proc dbo.s_Test2 
GO
create proc dbo.s_Test2 
as
    declare @t2 table (id2 int)    
    select t.id, t.xyz from dbo.t1 t join @t2 t2 on t2.id2 = t.id
GO
```

I get error: Invalid column name 'xyz'. Any ideas on why the #temp table version does not throw an error at stored proc creation time? 
Using SQL Server 2012, in case that matters.

Comment: My guess, and I can't verify this, is that a temp table doesn't have to be created in the same context that its used, only in the same connection, and its also not a permanent table, so SQL Server may well just throw up its hands and trust you. Because in this case it could validate it, but in many it couldn't. Whereas a table variable must be created in the same context and can therefore be validated.

Comment: Can't replicate on sql server 2016; both procedures are created without error.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - did the t1 table exist before creating the stored proc? 
i.e. did you run:   create table dbo.t1 (id int)     in another batch beforehand.

Comment: @MoeSisko, It could very well have been something like that. In hindsight, I wasn't at my sharpest yesterday ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with *Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation*. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190686(v=sql.105)

At compile time, the temp table/variable does not exist, so the statement won't be compiled. It will throw an error at execution time. I know, it sucks.

If you run the statement with table variable first without *dbo.t1* beeing create before, it also won't throw an error.

Comment: Hello osiris. Note that temporary tables and table variables are two different beasts. What you describe is for temporary tables, not table variables.

Comment: thanks. Related discussion on deferred name resolution:   http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html